# Retornar resultado de Query para uma variável - Asp Clássico

Tags: asp

É possível retornar o resultado de uma query para uma variável no asp clássico?

exemplo:

```
<%
    dim retorno as string
    set minha_conexao = dao.open()
    set rs = minha_conexao.execute("Select max(data) from minha_tabela")
%>
```

**Nesse ponto o retorno da query será apenas um valor, como faço para atribuir essa informação para uma variável.**

Tentei fazer o set retorno = rs(0), no entanto não está retornando.

Comment: Chegou a tentar o `rs.fields(0)`?

Comment: também não traz retorno

Comment: @LePy Tentou rs("NomeDaColuna")   ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sugiro fazer assim:

```
set rs = minha_conexao.execute("Select max(data) as max_data from minha_tabela")
retorno = rs("max_data")
```

Assim você põe na variável retorno o valor do recordset que a query retorna. Deu pra entender? Abs! LC